# If $(u_n)\to 0$, find if the quotient of Gagliardo seminorms $\frac{[u_n]^2_{s_1}}{[u_n]^2_{s_2}}$ is $o(1)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, partial-differential-equations, fractional-calculus, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $n\ge 2$, $0<s_1<s_2 <1$ and $(u_n)_n$ be a sequence such that
$$u_n\to 0 \text{ in } L^r(\Omega), \ \ r\in [1, 2^*_{s_2})$$
where $2^*_{s_2} = \frac{2n}{n-2s_2}$ is the critical Sobolev exponent for $s_2$ and
$$u_n\to 0 \text{ a.e.}$$

Let $[u_n]_{s_i}$, $i\in\{1, 2\}$ be the Gagliardo seminorm of $u_n$, i.e.
$$ [u_n]^2_{s_i}=\iint_{\mathbb R^{2n}} \frac{|(u_n(x) -u_n(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{n+2s_i}} dx dy.$$

I am trying to prove that (but I am not sure if that's true)
$$\frac{[u_n]^2_{s_1}}{[u_n]^2_{s_2}} = o(1) \quad\text{ as } n\to +\infty.$$

$\textbf{Notation:}$ we say that $f(x) = o(g(x))$ as $x\to x_0$ if $\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} =0.$

The only thing I got in mind so far is to use Proposition 2.2 (with $\Omega =\mathbb{R}^n$) of the paper Hitchhiker’s guide to the fractional Sobolev spaces to say that $[u_n]^2_{s_1} \le c [u_n]^2_{s_2}$ where $c=c(n, s_1)$ to say that
$$\frac{[u_n]^2_{s_1}}{[u_n]^2_{s_2}}\le 1,$$
but it does not help me to say or not if $\frac{[u_n]^2_{s_1}}{[u_n]^2_{s_2}} = o(1)$.

I hope someone could help. Thank you.

Comment: In which space is $u_n$ and in what sense does it converge to $0$ ?

Comment: @Gribouillis information added. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As it is currently stated, the conjecture is false.**

Take $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ a non-zero smooth function. Let $u_n := \frac{1}{n} \phi$. On the one hand, $u_n \to 0$ in any $L^r(\Omega)$ (and in fact, in any space). On the other hand
$$
\frac{[u_n]_{s_1}^2}{[u_n]_{s_2}^2} = \frac{[\phi]_{s_1}^2}{[\phi]_{s_2}^2} \neq o(1).
$$
You probably want to add another assumption preventing this situation.